# not getting email in user feedback form created with asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, email

I am creating user feedback form using asp.net with c#.When user enter his message in textbox and click enter button dat time i am not getting de mail of dat message..

This is my code:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
public partial class FeedbackPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public SmtpDeliveryMethod DeliveryMethod { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
        MailAddress To = new MailAddress(email.Text.ToString(),            name.Text.ToString());
        MailAddress From = new MailAddress("MyEmailId");
        Message.To.Add(To);
        Message.From = From;
        Message.Subject = subject.Text.ToString();
        Message.Body = msgg.Text.ToString();
        Message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        Message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyEmailId, "MyPassword");
        smtp.Credentials = cred;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        try
        {
            smtp.Send(Message);
            Response.Write("Your msg has been snd");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error!" + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing quote (") after MyEmailId.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're sending the message to the email address the user entered, from yourself. You'll only get it if you send it to your own address.

What you should do is send it to yourself from yourself as the user's email address may not be allowed to use your smtp server, and put the user email on the subject line, or in the body.

Or you could just use a mailto://myemail@mydomain.com link.